# How to determine compression method of a ZIP/RAR file

Tags: algorithm, compression, zip, rar

I have a few zip and rar files that I'm working with, and I'm trying to analyze the properties of how each file was compressed (compression level, compression algorithm (e.g. deflate, LZMA, BZip2), dictionary size, word size, etc.), and I haven't figured out a way to do this yet.

Is there any way to analyze the files to determine these properties, with software or otherwise?

Cheers and thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest [hachoir-wx](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/hachoir-wx/0.3) to have a look at these files. [How to install a Python package](http://dubroy.com/blog/so-you-want-to-install-a-python-package/) or you can try [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython) with PyPM when using Windows. When you have the necessary hachoir packages installed, you can do something like this to run the GUI:

> python C:\Python27\Scripts\hachoir-wx

It enables you to browse through the data fields of RAR and ZIP files. See this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtwrA.jpg) for an example.

For RAR files, have a look at the [technote.txt](http://ams.cern.ch/AMS/amsexch/arch/rar/technote.txt) file that is in the WinRAR installation directory. This gives detailed information of the RAR specification. You will probably be interested in these:

```
 HEAD_FLAGS      Bit flags: 2 bytes
                 0x10 - information from previous files is used (solid flag)
                 bits 7 6 5 (for RAR 2.0 and later)
                      0 0 0    - dictionary size   64 KB
                      0 0 1    - dictionary size  128 KB
                      0 1 0    - dictionary size  256 KB
                      0 1 1    - dictionary size  512 KB
                      1 0 0    - dictionary size 1024 KB
                      1 0 1    - dictionary size 2048 KB
                      1 1 0    - dictionary size 4096 KB
                      1 1 1    - file is directory
```

Dictionary size can be found in the WinRAR GUI too.

```
 METHOD          Packing method 1 byte
                 0x30 - storing
                 0x31 - fastest compression
                 0x32 - fast compression
                 0x33 - normal compression
                 0x34 - good compression
                 0x35 - best compression
```

And [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAR) also knows this:

> The RAR compression utility is proprietary, with a closed algorithm. RAR is owned by Alexander L. Roshal, the elder brother of Eugene Roshal. Version 3 of RAR is based on Lempel-Ziv (LZSS) and prediction by partial matching (PPM) compression, specifically the PPMd implementation of PPMII by Dmitry Shkarin.

For ZIP files I would start by having a look at the [specifications](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) and the [ZIP Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29). These are probably interesting:

```
  general purpose bit flag: (2 bytes)
  compression method: (2 bytes)
```

Comment: The METHOD byte for the first file is typically found at offset 0x2D.

Answer (score 19):

This is a fairly old question, but I wanted to throw in my two cents anyway since some of the methods above weren't as easy for me to use.

You can also determine this with 7-Zip.  After opening the archive there is a column for method of compression:

[image: 7zip properties]

Comment: Windows File Explorer also has this column available; though you may need to add it once the zip is open... right-click the table heading and ensure the 'Method' option is ticked / checked.

Answer (score 11):

For ZIP - yes, zipinfo

For RAR, the headers are easily found with either 7Zip or WinRAR, read the attached documentation

Comment: Thanks for your hint! I needed to find out what ZIP setting MS Word uses, when it generates .DOCX files. A DOCX file is a ZIP archive, containing several XML files and your embedded media files. These you can batch process with the tools of your choice, but then at the end you need to repack it to a ZIP file with settings which MS Word accepts! I used zipinfo to analyze the DOCX files MS Word had written. Should I come a final conclusion about the DOCX ZIP format, I will post it here.

Answer (score 8):

Via 7-Zip (or p7zip) command line:

```
7z l -slt archive.file
```

If looking specifically for the compression method:

```
7z l -slt archive.file | grep -e '^---' -e '^Path =' -e '^Method ='
```

Comment: I also could have used [`grep -E '^((---)|(Path =)|(Method =))'`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37316/13308).

Answer (score 2):

The [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) python module can be used to get info about the zipfile.
The `ZipInfo` class provides information like `filename`, `compress_type`, `compress_size`, `file_size` etc...

Python snippet to get filename and the compress type of files in a zip archive

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile(path_to_zipfile, 'r') as zip:
    for info in zip.infolist():
        print(f'filename: {info.filename}')
        print(f'compress type: {info.compress_type}')
```

This would list all the filenames and their corresponding compression type(integer), which can be used to look up the compression method.
You can get a lot more [info](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipinfo-objects) about the files using infolist().

*The python module linked in the accepted answer is not available, `zipfile` module might help*

Answer (score 1):

For the ZIP files, there is a command zipinfo.

Comment: When I enter that into my console, it says that no such command was found.

Comment: `sudo apt install unzip`

Comment: [Version](https://superuser.com/questions/120354/analyzing-properties-of-a-zip-file#comment2565404_120360) for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The type is easy, just look at the file headers (`PK` and `Rar`).

As for the rest, I doubt that information is available in the compressed content.

Comment: Yes, it is available (at least for rar). But how to get it obviously depends on the specific file format.

Comment: If the information wasn't available, it wouldn't be possible to decompress the data.