# manipulate files within a rar file

Tags: rar

I have downloaded a movie which is split into 5 rar files due to its large size. The first 4 parts of the file are downloaded from one site while the 5th file is downloaded from a different site since the link to the fifth file in the original site is broken. The problem is the fifth file is in a sub folder while the first four files are in the root folder so i'm unable to merge the files to get the avi file. 
Is there a way i can manipulate the fifth file and move it to the root folder?
Part1.avi
Part2.avi
Part3.avi
Part4.avi
subfolder\part5.avi

My last resort will be to redownload the first 4 parts of the files from the second site but if possible I would like to avoid that.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to just download those 4 other parts too. I see issues that could complicate it, but it's possible.

The first thing to ask yourself is how many data is in each RAR file available? Is this the same for both RAR sets? Probably not. Set 2 has the path stored, thus making it larger. Which of both sets contains the most data? If it's the first set, then you would need to download part 4 from the second set too because otherwise there would be a gab of data that you don't have.

The second issue: are the archives compressed or not? Not so much of an issue if the first set is, but I don't see a possibility to unpack the second set if compression is used. You talk about a movie, so unless an idiot packed the movie, my guess is that no compression will be used.

There could an nfo file stored in the set with the folder, but the positive thing is that you'll have more data in part 5 than needed, but I expect this to be the case anyway.

Here is my experiment for the best case scenario: the data in the archives are equal size and no compression is used. My idea to solve this is to edit the name in part5 with a hex editor, but no, the archives I created don't have equal data, so it'll be a case that matches your setting.

I created the test files. I renamed part5 to match the first set: CRC error while trying to extract. This is because part 5 has too much data. Undo the rename.
Extract part of the movie from the first set: While extracting with WinRAR, check the box "Keep broken files" in the Miscellaneous section.

To get the data out of the last RAR file, use the following tool: [hachoir-wx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896487/how-to-determine-compression-method-of-a-zip-rar-file/6914588#6914588)

Open the file[0]/ block and right click compressed_data. Choose Dump To Disk.... Now you have your movie in 2 parts that still need to be merged, but part 2 has a bit too much data.

What you need to do next is to copy the right bytes to a new file. This is the formula to calculate what needs to be chopped away from file 2:

```
(size part 1) + (size part 2 - X) = total size movie file
```

The total file size can be read out from WinRAR. The other sizes you have and X can be calculated.

You can join both files by writing a small script or maybe you can do this with a hex editor. A Python script could look like this:

```
folder = "C:\movie"
name_part_1 = os.path.join(folder, "movie_part1.avi")
name_part_2 = os.path.join(folder, "movie_part2.avi")
out = os.path.join(folder, "good_name.avi")
x = 1337

with open(out, "wb") as good:
    with open(name_part_1, "rb") as one:
        good.write(one.read())
    with open(name_part_2, "rb") as two:
        two.seek(x)
        good.write(two.read())
```

Comment: I get the following error when trying to install hachoir-wx  

No local packages or download links found for wxPython>=2.6.3
Best match: None'

Comment: This means that you have to install wxPython first.